# Angular2 radio button not working with material design

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-material

I am using Angular2 with material design and I want to have two radio buttons representing a true false state (boolean). The problem is that when the page loads the `org.nda` value is set to either true or false but none radio button is selected. If I click on any radio, the button is selected properly and on save the right value is saved. So the problem is only with the initial page load, when none radio button is checked. Notice that if I remove the material related classes from labels, the radio buttons are working correctly. I checked similar questions but none of them worked with my case. Any ideas?

```
<label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="option-no">
    <input id="option-no" class="mdl-radio__button" type="radio" name="nda" [value]=false
           [ngModel]="{checked: !org.nda}"
           (ngModelChange)="org.nda = false">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">No</span>
</label>

<label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="option-yes">
    <input id="option-yes" class="mdl-radio__button" type="radio" name="nda" [value]=true
           [ngModel]="{checked: org.nda}"
           (ngModelChange)="org.nda = true">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Yes</span>
</label>
```